# Is jQuery / Backbone mangling my UTF-8 characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, utf-8

I'm migrating the front-end of a site from an old YUI2 framework to jQuery/BackBone.  The PHP/mySQL back-end hasn't changed.  All is well, except UTF-8 characters sent via Backbone save (via $.ajax) are getting mangled and I can't figure out why.

Here's what I do know:

1. The backend handles UTF-8 fine.  It hasn't changed as part of this rebuild.  I know that's true, because when I change the config to load the old YUI2 front-end, UTF-8 characters work fine.  They're escaped in Javascript using `escape(string)`, passed via `YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest` as JSON in an `XMLHttpRequest`, unescaped and saved in the database as UTF-8, fully readable and nice.
2. In the new front-end, I've added `<meta charset="UTF-8">` and `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` to all page headers.  The old front-end didn't have these settings.  I only mention that because it's a difference.
3. In the new front-end, UTF-8 characters work fine when I save them as a `<form>` submit.
4. I  the new front-end, the request Content-Type looks fine in the console.  `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

How am I passing data in the new front-end?

- Sometimes via a regular Backbone model.save(), other times passing data in options like this:

  ```
  var text = $('#input-' + targetId).val();

  var atts = {};
  atts['target_id'] = targetId;
  atts['user_id'] = userId;
  atts['text'] = text;

  var comment = new Comment(atts);

  comment.save(
      {},
      {
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/api/comment?',
          data: atts,
          processData: true,
          success: function(comment, response){
             //success handling
          },
          error: function(model, response){
             //error handling
          },
      },
  );
  ```

So, what do these mangled special characters look like?

- As entered in the input: テクス テクサン テクス テクサン
- When I pass **completely unescaped**, they look fine in the request in the console in the Form Data section:  `text: テクス テクサン テクス テクサン`, but mangled in the database as `ãã¯ã¹ ãã¯ãµã³ ãã¯ã¹ ãã¯ãµã³`.  Perhaps this is a clue, I don't know.  I've always escaped user-entered text when passing via AJAX.
- When I `escape(text)`, I get `text:%u30C6%u30AF%u30B9%20%u30C6%u30AF%u30B5%u30F3%20%u30C6%u30AF%u30B9%20%u30C6%u30AF%u30B5%u30F3` in the console, and `テクス%20テクサン%20テクス%20テクサン` in the database.

That's better, but it's different from the old front end, which uses `escape(text)`, passes `%u30C6%u30AF%u30B9%20%u30C6%u30AF%u30B5%u30F3%20%u30C6%u30AF%u30B9%20%u30C6%u30AF%u30B5%u30F3`, shows in the console as `text: (unable to decode value)` and saves in the database unescaped as テクス テクサン テクス テクサン

- Of course, it's 2016 now and we all know `escape()` should not be used.  We should use `encodeURIComponent()` instead.  So, when I `encodeURIComponent(text)`, here's what I get in the console: `text: %E3%83%86%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%20%E3%83%86%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%20%E3%83%86%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%20%E3%83%86%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3` which is saved in the database as `%E3%83%86%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%20%E3%83%86%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%20%E3%83%86%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%20%E3%83%86%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3`  That technically works, and I can always `decodeURIComponent` when displaying this text, but that's a real pain and it's just masking the issue.
- I've also tried `unescape(encodeURIComponent(text))` with the following result: `text:ãã¯ã¹ ãã¯ãµã³ ãã¯ã¹ ãã¯ãµã³` in the console, `Ã£ÂÂÃ£ÂÂ¯Ã£ÂÂ¹ Ã£ÂÂÃ£ÂÂ¯Ã£ÂÂµÃ£ÂÂ³ Ã£ÂÂÃ£ÂÂ¯Ã£ÂÂ¹ Ã£ÂÂÃ£ÂÂ¯Ã£ÂÂµÃ£ÂÂ³` in the database.

It seems that there's some sort of double-encoding going on, or perhaps the back-end was built to handle the specific format that's passed via the YUI2 Async request.  I don't know.

Any ideas for what I should try next?  What are the best practices?

Answer (score 2):

Now that I've had a night to sleep on it, I've realized a few things and I think I've found a solution.

It's clear now that the **old front-end** wasn't passing data correctly...that's evidenced by the `text: (unable to decode value)` in the console when sending the request. Somehow, the PHP back-end was able to handle the passed text even though there was no decoding in the api or db storage classes.  That's a mystery for another day.

Here's what I did to fix the problem:

1. Pass text from the front-end as `encodeURIComponent(text)`
2. Decode the text in the PHP back-end api using `$comment->set_text(urldecode(Request::get('text')));`

The text is stored in the DB unescaped as readable UTF-8 characters and I don't need to do anything special on read/display.  I will need to add the `urldecode` to all of my api endpoints on the back-end, but that feels like a solid approach, so I think it's resolved.

I'd be interested to hear thoughts on the use of `encodeURIComponent` on the front-end and `urldecode` on the back-end. Is this the best way to solve the problem?

Comment: You actually never want to use the `escape()` Javascript function. It's broken and has [long been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape). For how to set up PHP on the server side, read [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through). On a broader note, you never want to do any manual data encoding at all. Libraries have been written on the client and the server that encode/decode data automatically for you. Use them.

Comment: @Tomalek, for front-end/Javascript, what libraries are you talking about?

Comment: Any library that does Ajax (or even higher abstractions, like the stuff Backbone provides) will encode values for you.  You only work with data itself, the underlying library manages UTF-8 or JSON encoding. If you find yourself building your own encoding routines then it's likely that you are either missing API functions in the libraries that you already use - or that you should add a library that does it.